# Конвертация EDITABLE  TO STRING

Tags: android, android-edittext

Никак не получается перевести из типа `Editable` в тип `String`.
Помогите разобраться.

```
 EditText input = new EditText(this);
 input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
 input.setHint("Example: TEST");
 String name=input.getText().toString();//Введенные данные

 name(остается типом Editable)
```

Спасибо, проверка показывает, что `name` типа `String`.

Однако значение переменной исчезает если я ввожу текст в поле `EditText` руками.

А если делаю так (программно создам текст):

```
 EditText input = new EditText(this);
 input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
 input.setHint("Example: TEST");
 input.setText("Some data");--Программно создаю текст
 String name=input.getText().toString();
```

то `name="Some data"` тобишь все нормально.

А если убрать приведение к типу `String`:

```
 Editable name=input.getText();
```

то все нормально ввожу руками текст который получает переменная name, однако это не `String` тип а `Editable`.

Comment: почему ты так думаешь?)

Answer (score 4):

Быть такого не может. Проверь

```
if(name instanceof Editable) 
     Log.i("TAG", "Не может быть!"); 
else 
     Log.i("TAG", "Чудес не бывает, а жаль...");
```

Comment: Спасибо разобрался